# Tmux not starting after closing terminal on freeze session

Tags: tmux

My tmux panes became frozen and I decided to close the terminal because I somehow thought that would fix it. Now, when I run the `tmux` command in my home directory, tmux's usual green bar doesn't show up at the bottom and it looks like I'm being asked to enter input infinitely.

I'm using tmux 3.1 and there are two tmux-client log files in my home directory, which are shown below. The second log file appeared when I was trying to fix the issue. Also, when I try to open the files I was editing using tmux, I get an error saying that swap files were found for them.

**tmux-client-92612.log:**

```
1588823002.943027 client started (92612): version 3.1, socket /private/tmp/tmux-501/default, protocol 8
1588823002.943122 on Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64; libevent 2.1.11-stable (select)
1588823002.943243 socket is /private/tmp/tmux-501/default
1588823002.943264 trying connect
1588823002.943339 add peer 0x10adb5000: 6 (0x0)
1588823002.944435 sending message 100 to peer 0x10adb5000 (4 bytes)
1588823002.944453 sending message 101 to peer 0x10adb5000 (15 bytes)
1588823002.944460 sending message 102 to peer 0x10adb5000 (13 bytes)
1588823002.944466 sending message 108 to peer 0x10adb5000 (14 bytes)
1588823002.944483 sending message 104 to peer 0x10adb5000 (0 bytes)
1588823002.944490 sending message 107 to peer 0x10adb5000 (4 bytes)
1588823002.944496 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (28 bytes)
1588823002.944502 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (16 bytes)
1588823002.944508 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (20 bytes)
1588823002.944514 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (57 bytes)
1588823002.944520 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (25 bytes)
1588823002.944527 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (53 bytes)
1588823002.944533 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (12 bytes)
1588823002.944541 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (66 bytes)
1588823002.944548 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (50 bytes)
1588823002.944554 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (18 bytes)
1588823002.944560 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (17 bytes)
1588823002.944566 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (14 bytes)
1588823002.944574 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (19 bytes)
1588823002.944580 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (8 bytes)
1588823002.944586 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (19 bytes)
1588823002.944592 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (15 bytes)
1588823002.944598 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adb5000 (22 bytes)
1588823002.944604 sending message 106 to peer 0x10adb5000 (0 bytes)
1588823002.944613 sending message 200 to peer 0x10adb5000 (4 bytes)
1588823002.944619 client loop enter
```

**tmux-client-92706.log:**

```
1588823622.214067 client started (92706): version 3.1, socket /private/tmp/tmux-501/default, protocol 8
1588823622.214123 on Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64; libevent 2.1.11-stable (select)
1588823622.214161 socket is /private/tmp/tmux-501/default
1588823622.214178 trying connect
1588823622.214253 add peer 0x10adba000: 6 (0x0)
1588823622.215324 sending message 100 to peer 0x10adba000 (4 bytes)
1588823622.215342 sending message 101 to peer 0x10adba000 (15 bytes)
1588823622.215348 sending message 102 to peer 0x10adba000 (13 bytes)
1588823622.215354 sending message 108 to peer 0x10adba000 (14 bytes)
1588823622.215370 sending message 104 to peer 0x10adba000 (0 bytes)
1588823622.215376 sending message 107 to peer 0x10adba000 (4 bytes)
1588823622.215382 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (28 bytes)
1588823622.215388 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (16 bytes)
1588823622.215393 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (20 bytes)
1588823622.215399 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (57 bytes)
1588823622.215405 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (25 bytes)
1588823622.215410 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (53 bytes)
1588823622.215416 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (12 bytes)
1588823622.215422 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (66 bytes)
1588823622.215427 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (50 bytes)
1588823622.215433 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (18 bytes)
1588823622.215438 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (17 bytes)
1588823622.215444 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (14 bytes)
1588823622.215450 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (19 bytes)
1588823622.215455 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (8 bytes)
1588823622.215461 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (19 bytes)
1588823622.215466 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (15 bytes)
1588823622.215472 sending message 105 to peer 0x10adba000 (22 bytes)
1588823622.215477 sending message 106 to peer 0x10adba000 (0 bytes)
1588823622.215485 sending message 200 to peer 0x10adba000 (4 bytes)
1588823622.215491 client loop enter
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the tmux server has hung. Does it work again if you do `pkill -WINCH tmux`?

If no, you will need to do `pkill -9 tmux` and restart it.

Do you remember what you were doing when it hung? Can you reproduce?

Comment: pkill -9 tmux worked! Thanks. I was working, my entire tmux session seemed to freeze, which I believe was due to me pressing something like Ctr-S, and I closed my terminal using the window close button. Then, I couldn't open tmux after opening the terminal again.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. `C-s` is the xoff flow control key - `C-q` will undo it. But tmux should disable that entirely. Can you reproduce this again? If so please open an issue at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues.

Comment: I'll try and reproduce it because it keeps happening and my only solution is pkill -9 tmux. I'll open an issue there once I do.